# Cloning Objects hierarchy (including one to one , one to many recursively) in hibernate with a different revision

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, clone

I am having an object hierarchy as below

Object1 is mapped to Object2 by OneToOne
Object2 is mapped to Object3 by OneToMany

So, Obj1 will have exactly one Obj2, and Obj2 will have many Obj3.

My requirement is to clone all the objects in the hierarchy, with a different value to a specific variable(ex String revision;), lets say revision . In simple terms, I should have a master revision, and another three more revisions directing to  three organizations. According to the requirement, each organization will have its own copy , where it will refer and make changes. So basically I need to clone the object hierarchy while setting the revision to "ORG1", "ORG2" and "ORG3". Each object will have a
String revision;
so when I am cloning, I  should be able to set the revision such as 
obj1.setRevision("ORG1); //when I am setting a clone for the organization1.

I used the below mechanism

```
Object1 obj1ToBeClone  = Object1Service.findObject1ById(1l);
Object1 object1Cloned  =(Object1)SerializationHelper.clone(obj1ToBeClone);
object1Cloned.setId(null)
object1Service.saveObject1(object1Cloned);
```

I have used spring and hibernate to define the dao layer.

Yet, I noted I still have to get Object2 from object1Cloned and set the id to null and save obj2 using a session in order to clone obj2. Code goes as follows

```
Object2 obj2 = object1Cloned.getObject2();
obj2.setId(null);
```

This is how I have set the relationship in Object1.

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name ="object2_id")
private Object2 object2;
```

My Questions are,

1. Do I need to fetch all the objects in the Objects hierarchy and set
   the id to null, using setID(null) in order to generate a new object
   in the database.
2. Can you propose me a way to set the revision to a
   specific String such as "ORG1", "ORG2" etc, so that it will be set
   to all the objects of the object hierarchy.?
3. How to avoid the following so I dnt have to traverse down the object hierarchy and set the id (also the revision string)to null of each individual object

   Object2 obj2 = object1Cloned.getObject2();
   obj2.setId(null);

Comment: Just want to know how we can clone objects with the relations using Hibernate..